# Match first only instance of a character

Tags: regex, xpath

I'm trying to match *only* the first instance of a character in a string like `sdtmig-3-1-2` with [XPath::replace](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) and replace it with a `/` so that the resulting string is `sdtmig/3-1-2`.  I cannot guarantee anything else about the pattern other than that it will have one or more dashes in it.  I'm having a ton of difficulty finding a regex pattern that consistently matches only that particular first instance of `-`.

I feel like I came close with:

```
(?:.+?)(-)(?:.+)
```

But this also matches the full string as well, so it is no good.

Please do not offer solutions using anything but plain regular expressions that would work on https://regex101.com.  **The "flavor" of regex should abide by XPath/XQuery semantics (https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#regexs).  I cannot control the global flag on the regexp search.**

Comment: what programming language?

Comment: Why do you want a regex for that?

Comment: Regex only.  Please do not offer solutions using anything but plain regular expressions that would work on https://regex101.com.  The "flavor" of regex should abide by XPath/XQuery semantics (https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#regexs).

Comment: I want regex because I must use regex.  I cannot use any other language for this purpose.

Comment: With all due respect to Wiktor, this is *NOT* a duplicate of the previously asked question.  That question was specific to Notepad++ which has different restrictions and semantics than XPath matches/replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without introducing the [`g` (global flag)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global#Description), the regular expression will match at most a single occurrence. This is equivalent to the plain [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) call like `'sdtmig-3-1-2'.replace('-', '/')` which results in `"sdtmig/3-1-2"`.

Please see a [plain regular expression usage (make sure the global modifier is turned off and use `/-/` regular expression with a substitution of `/`)](https://regex101.com/r/a0Ivtj/1).

For example:

```js
console.log('sdtmig-3-1-2'.replace(/-/, '/'));
```

With the global flag, it would replace all the occurrences:

```js
console.log('sdtmig-3-1-2'.replace(/-/g, '/'));
```

You can also use lazy prefix match of anything before the first occurrence and replace the matched groups with their original contents so they wrap around the replaced character. Please see the regular expression for this:
[`(.*?)-(.*)` and a substitution of `$1/$2`](https://regex101.com/r/Ge2AhY/1).
This should work with [XQuery replace function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-replace).

```js
console.log('sdtmig-3-1-2'.replace(/(.*?)-(.*)/, '$1/$2'));
```

Comment: This has to match XPath/XQuery "matches" semantics which does not appear to allow control of the global flag.

Comment: Please use `(.*?)-(.*)` with subsitutiion of `$1/$2` - https://regex101.com/r/Ge2AhY/1
xQuery should support this for the [replace function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-replace).

Comment: ^^^^This!^^^^  Change your answer and I will upvote all day!

Comment: @robross0606 The edited answer already includes this paragraph at the bottom.