# Use XPath:Replace on first instance of a single character

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to replace *only* the first instance of a character in a string like `fred-3-1-2` with [XPath::replace](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) and replace it with a `/` so that the resulting string is `fred/3-1-2`.  I cannot guarantee anything else about the original string other than that it will have one or more dashes in it.  I'm having a ton of difficulty finding a regex pattern that works with XPath::replace and consistently matches only that particular first instance of `-`.

I feel like I came close with:

```
(?:.+?)(-)(?:.+)
```

But this also matches the full string as well, so it is no good.

Please do not offer solutions using anything but plain regular expressions that would work on https://regex101.com.  **The "flavor" of regex should abide by XPath/XQuery semantics (https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#regexs).**

Comment: Why did you create another thread with the same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57564278/match-first-only-instance-of-a-character - and you also got an answer there, you even commented with "^^^^This!^^^^ Change your answer and I will upvote all day!"

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
replace('fred-3-1-2', '^([^-]*)-','$1/')
```

[Check it.](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/41ec4f194c3026f8cfe21b616400c727) Result:

```
fred/3-1-2
```

Meaning:

> From the start, match any non `-` character followed by one `-`
>   character, replace the match by the first captured group plus `/`
>   character

**Do note:** XPath/XQuery follows Perl regexp. The description in XML Schema you cite is extended in XPath/Xquery with the [followings](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#string.match): *"Matching the Start and End of the String", "Reluctant Quantifiers", "Captured Sub-Expressions", "Back-References"*

Answer (score 0):

**Pure XPath 1.0 solution** -- no regular expressions:

```
concat(substring-before('fred-3-1-2', '-'), '/', substring-after('fred-3-1-2', '-'))
```

**In case the string is contained in a variable `$s` and it isn't known that it contains a `-`**, then use:

```
concat(
       substring(concat(substring-before($s, '-'), '/', substring-after($s, '-')), 
          1 div contains($s, '-')
         ),
       substring($s, 1 div not(contains($s, '-')))
       )
```

---

**XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="s" select="'fred-3-1-2'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="t" select="'fred+3+1+2'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before('fred-3-1-2', '-'), '/', substring-after('fred-3-1-2', '-'))"/>
    =================
    <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat(
       substring(concat(substring-before($s, '-'), '/', substring-after($s, '-')),
          1 div contains($s, '-')
         ),
       substring($s, 1 div not(contains($s, '-')))
       )"/>
    ===============
    <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat(
       substring(concat(substring-before($t, '-'), '/', substring-after($t, '-')),
          1 div contains($t, '-')
         ),
       substring($t, 1 div not(contains($t, '-')))
       )"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is applied on any XML file (not used), it evaluates the XPath expressions provided on this answer and produces the wanted, correct results: if the string contains `-` then its first (only) occurence in the string is replaced in the result of the evaluation; if the string doesn't contain any hyphens, then the result is the same string unchanged:

```
fred/3-1-2
=================
fred/3-1-2
===============
fred+3+1+2
```